# Loopback send email with attachment is not working with dynamic

Tags: node.js, sendmail, loopbackjs, email-attachments, strongloop

I have model where i can store the values and send an email. I need to send an email with attachment but its is not working it is throwing some error.
can anyone help me how to send an email with attachment.

career.js

```
'use strict';
const app = require('../../server/server');
module.exports = function(Career) {

    Career.afterRemote('create', function(context, remoteMethodOutput, next) { 
        next(); 
     // console.log(context.result) 
    Career.app.models.Email.send({ 
            to: 'lakshmipriya.l@gmail.com', 
            from: 'lakshmipriya.l@gmail.com', 
            subject: 'Career Form', 
            html: '<em>Hi,</em>',
            attachments: [
                {   // utf-8 string as an attachment
                    path: './files/resume/860e032e-a8e6-478a-beeb-6a7225ead701.docx'

                }
             ], 
            },
           function(err, mail) { 
                // console.log(context.result.email)
            console.log('email sent!'); 
            console.log(err); 
        }); 
    });
```

Comment: Hi, what error are you getting?

Comment: D:\Lakshmi\api\common\models\career.js:23
            cb(err);
ReferenceError: cb is not defined
    at D:\Lakshmi\api\common\models\career.js:23:13
    at transporter.send.args (D:\Lakshmi\api\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\mailer\index.js:226:21)
    at connection.send (D:\Lakshmi\api\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-transport\index.js:239:32)
    at callback (D:\Lakshmi\api\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:435:13)

Comment: @lakshmipriya Please add the error stacktrace in the question instead of posting it in the comments.

Comment: Found the solution instead of afterRemote i need to use the   Career.observe('after save', function(ctx, next) {

Answer (score 0):

Per the stack trace, this line is calling an undefined function: `cb(err)`.

To get the reason for the mail failure you'll want to print the `err`.

Comment: attachment is working but i want to set it as dynamic. now i have given the static file name as attachment. but i want to set as dynamic. the attachment.json is in another modle. how to fetch the file name in this model and send

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `cb` you should call `next`, there is no cb function defined in your code (probably you took the code from 2 different examples, that's why cb is there).
Secondly, before you will call next(err) I would check if the error exists, otherwise, your code will call the next tick if there is no error.

Comment: i want to fetch the file name from other module ans send through email is it possible

Comment: is it possible to get the file name in one module and pass it to other module

Comment: if you have defined a relationship between those 2 then I guess yes, otherwise you may not know which file/entity to look for.